# Is deleting your post and comment good or bad?

Tags: support

It's not been that much since I joined this community, so not being familiar with rule of this community I have deleted my two post.

One question that I learned from comment is that was too broad for this community. I tried to generalize it but wasn't able to and deleted it. Had one upvote on that question.

And other answer that I posted yesterday, on rushing to answer forget to mention the original author of that content. Which was a bigger mistake than other one, had two down votes and deleted it.

Main thing is that I learned from my mistake and I won't let it happen over again. 
So should I have deleted it or not?

Comment: Without judging the content from the deleted posts (since I don't have enough rep): 1) if it's considered too broad and you can't generalize it, then you're doing the community a service by deleting it. 2) if you can salvage it by editing it (add a proper reference?), then I think you can undelete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel that your post was not useful to the site, then you may delete it if you so wish.  Remember that, you as author, can still edit the deleted post to improve it and then undelete it later.

Generally, there are no negative effects of deletion.  However, deletion of your post is recorded.  If you make a habit of deleting posts, a black mark will go against your account and, worst case, you could receive an automatic post suspension.  The details of the criteria for this automated process are not disclosed by SE.

But to repeat, a newish user deleting a couple of posts that are downvoted will not receive such a ban.  Especially given that you have other, well received posts.  You are doing the site a favour by removing unhelpful or incorrect posts.

Incidentally, removing your own comments has no such risk of black marks.  Comments are meant to be temporary.